# ScrollLeft doesn't run

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have seen this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/306/ that is implemented with `scrollleft`.

Now I have done a modification.

This is my script but is doesn't run: http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/39/

What is the problem?

Comment: I know exactly _why_ it's not scrolling left/right but cannot give you a good solution because you have not explained what you're trying to do.  Why would you want a bunch of `li` items (without a `ul`) side by side each only containing a number "1"?  Weird.

Comment: Sorry, its is that I want to do, a list of links in same line with scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/63/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve by putting a list of `1`'s inside `li` elements without the required `ul` container.

Simply replacing the text with the `img` element in your code demonstrates that it's functional.

http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/54/

The reason you can't scroll your list of `1`'s left/right is because it's wrapping.  If you increase the height, you can see it wrapping below.  Since it's wrapping down, there is nothing there to scroll side to side.

http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/55/

The solution is to remove the `float` on the `li`'s and add `display:inline;` which causes them all to stay in one line.  Then add `white-space: nowrap;` to the container to prevent wrapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/75/

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll amount was too small for you to notice the movement.

Also, you can animate to `+=10px` and jQuery will automatically add that value to the current value.

```
var scroll = 100;
var speed = 200;

$('#left').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollLeft': '-=' + scroll
    }, speed);
});

$('#right').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollLeft': '+=' + scroll
    }, speed);
});

$('#up').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollTop': '-=' + scroll
    }, speed);
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        'scrollTop': '+=' + scroll
    }, speed);
});
```

Also, don't close the `<img />` tag with a closing tag. `<img />` tags are self-closing:

```
<img src="http://nyquil.org/uploads/IndianHeadTestPattern16x9.png" />
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/311/**

Comment: Sorry but in my example don't runs. This is my example. http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/39/

Comment: My example that the content is a li not runs. My browser is chrome. I'm talking with this example. http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/39/

Comment: @ sparky672 Yes I put float, because I want that it has in horizontal. Thanks